# convert pdf into small chunks of data(many chunks per page)?

Tags: html, pdf

I have a pdf file and I need to get get small pieces of data from it. 
It is structured like this :

> Page1:
>
> Question 1
>
> ......................................
>
> ......................................
>
> Question 2
>
> ......................................
>
> ......................................
>
> Page End

I want to get Question 1 and Question 2 as separate html files, which contain text and image.

I've tried

`pdftohtml -c pdffile.pdf output.html`

And I got files with png images, but how to do I cut the Image into smaller chunks to fit the size of each Question (I want to separate each question into individual files)?

P.S. I have alot of pdf files, so a command-line tool would be nice.

Comment: check this website - http://smallpdf.com/split-pdf, once you split the pages, convert the same into jpeg images if you need!!

Comment: @Aru I forgot to specify this in the question, I have alot of pdf files, so a commandline tool would be nice.

Comment: try this http://www.tiffsoftware.com/Batch-pdf-splitter.html  or  http://pdf-split.com/download, hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you an approach on how I would go about it. You mention, that every page in your `PDF` document might have multiple questions and you basically want have one `HTML` file for every question.

It's great if [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) works for you, but I also found another decent [command line utility](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) that you might want to [try out](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Quick-Start).

Ok, so assuming you have an HTML file converted from the PDF you initially had, you might want to use `csplit` or `awk` to split your file into multiple files based on the delimiter 'Question' in your case. (Side note- `csplit` and `awk` are linux specific utilites, but I'm sure there are alternatives if you are on Windows or a MAC. I haven't specifically tried the following code)

From a [relevant SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544197/splitting-a-file-in-linux-based-on-content) :

```
 csplit input.txt'/^Question$/' '{*}'

 awk '/Question/{filename=NR".txt"}; {print >filename}' input.txt
```

So, assuming this works, you will have a couple of *broken* html files. *Broken* because they'll be unsanitized  due to dangling `<` or `>` or some other stray `HTML` elements after the splitting.

So you could start by saving the initial `.html` as `.txt`, removing the `html`, `head` and `body` elements specifically and going through the general structure of how the program converts the `pdf` into `html`. I'm sure you'll see a pattern around how the string 'Quetion' is wrapped in an element and is something you can take care of. That is why I mention `.txt` files in the code snippets.

You will basically have a bunch of text files with just the content html and not the usual starting tags for an html file because we removed that initially. Then it's only a matter of reading each file, just taking care of the element that surrounds the string 'Question' and adding the `html`, `head` and `body` elements around the content and saving them as `.html` files. You could do this in any programming language of your choice that supports file reading and writing (would be a fun exercise)

I hope this gets you started in the right direction.